# How can you efficiently check values of large vectors in R?

Tags: r

One thing I want to do all the time in my R code is to test whether certain conditions hold for a vector, such as whether it contains any or all values equal to some specified value.  The `R`ish way to do this is to create a boolean vector and use any or all, for example:

```
any(is.na(my_big_vector))
all(my_big_vector == my_big_vector[[1]])
...
```

It seems really inefficient to me to allocate a big vector and fill it with values, just to throw it away (especially if `any()` or `all()` call can be short-circuited after testing only a couple of the values.  Is there a better way to do this, or should I just hand in my desire to write code that is both efficient and succinct when working in `R`?

Answer (score 3):

"*Cheap, fast, reliable: pick any two*" is a dry way of saying that you sometimes need to order your priorities when building or designing systems.

It is rather similar here: the cost of the concise expression is the fact that memory gets allocated behind the scenes. If that really is a problem, then you can always write a (compiled ?) routines to runs (quickly) along the vectors and uses only pair of values at a time.

You *can* trade off memory usage versus performance versus expressiveness, but is difficult to hit all three at the same time.

Comment: It would seem like the built in library ought to have functions that could tell you whether any value in a big vector was NA or equal to some value.  In Python, you could use generator comprehensions which would allocate a fixed amount of memory and short circuit the computation of any() or all().

Answer (score 0):

```
which(is.na(my_big_vector))
which(my_big_vector == 5)
which(my_big_vector < 3)
```

And if you want to count them...

```
length(which(is.na(my_big_vector)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not a good idea -- R is a very high-level language, so what you should do is to follow standards. This way R developers know what to optimize. You should also remember that while R is functional and lazy language, it is even possible that statement like

```
any(is.na(a))
```

can be recognized and executed as something like

```
.Internal(is_any_na,a)
```